# How to tell what class you extends?

Tags: php

Is there a function that tells what class you are extending? Like function_exists?

I want to use this in an __autoload function that if it detects a class that extends mysqli, then I will automatically connect it to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class foo { };
class bar extends foo {};
$bar = new bar();
echo get_parent_class($bar);
```

assuming bar extends `foo`, should echo `foo`

Comment: uhm... `$bar` is undefined, don't you mean `$foo`? get_parent_class: http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.get-parent-class.php